# Grounding Yourself When Working On Electronics

Tags: electricity, static, pc, static-electricity

I was wanting to discuss if using a wrist strap connected to a in unpainted screw on a pc power supply (this screw is a mounting screw it is not touching anything inside the power supply) that is not connected or mounted to a computer as a grounding device to avoid static electricity damaging components.

Of course the power would be switched off but it would be connected to the outlet.

Would this be an effective grounding procedure?

Would this still cause static electricity to transfer since electrons transfer to what electronic you are working on since the power supply is not connected it it (like for instance a pc)?

Comment: The current always wants to go through the shortest way. In your case, that way is the ground wire (or a metal part connected to that ground wire). If you touch the unpainted screw which touches the grounded metal case then, even if you are full of static charge, why would electrons go through the electronics instead of the "shortest" way? By the way, it doesn't matter if the circuit is powered or not.

Comment: PC chassis is connected to the outlet ground directly, so whether PC is on or off the grounding works the same.

Comment: @RohatKılıç Current DOES NOT flow via "the shortest path". This is an old explanation with some usefulness when the path impedances are very different from each other, but dangerously wrong in the real world. | Current divides in the inverse ratio to the impedances of th two paths. (Or resistances for pure resistive paths). eg if one path has 300 Ohms resistance and the second path has 100 Ohms resistance then the current will divide in the ration 1:3 respectively. The 100 Ohm path carries 3/4 of the current and the 300 Ohm path carries 1/4 of the current.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Sorry, I didn't say "flows", I said "wants to flow". And in this statement *"... why would electrons go through the electronics instead of the shortest way"* I intended to visualize the ridiculously high ratio of impedances between those two.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the other comments/replies, I'll add that an ESD wristband, by itself, doesn't provide much benefit if your goal is to prevent electrical overstress (EOS) due to electrostatic discharge (ESD). You also require a work surface made of engineered, static-dissipative material that is electrically bonded to the same ground as your ESD wristband.

---

**:: IMPORTANT ::**

Your work surface **should never be** a conductive material (e.g., metal) nor an insulating material (e.g., plastic laminate); it should only be a properly grounded, static-dissipative material.

Imagine handling a circuit card that has static charge on it and laying that card onto a metallic surface.  The instant the card contacts the metal surface there will be a **rapid transfer of charge** (ESD) between the work piece and the work surface. This rapid transfer of charge (think short duration, high current) can easily cause electrical overstress that destroys sensitive electronic components on the card.

Now imagine using a work surface that's covered with material like plastic laminate that is acts as an electrical insulator.  You place an item (e.g., your smartphone) onto the surface, and static charge is transferred from the item onto the surface. If you now remove the item from the surface, you now have an island of static charge on that work surface. If you now deposit your circuit card onto (or even nearby) that statically-charged island, the electrostatic field can damage sensitive components on the card if the island's electric field strength is large enough.

---

So in addition to wearing an ESD wristband you also need to use a *static dissipative* work surface that is electrically bonded to the same ground as your ESD wristband, and you need ESD-safe hand tools.

Bottom line, you want to ensure

- controlled (i.e., low current) transfer of electric charge between you, the work surface, and the work piece, and
- that you, your hand tools, the work piece, and the work surface are all roughly the same electrostatic potential.

If you frequently work with exposed electronic components/circuits, there are some relatively inexpensive ESD mat kits you can buy.  Try an Internet search using the keywords "esd field service kit" or "esd mat kit" or similar.  Other useful Internet searches would be "managing esd" and "managing electrical overstress".

*(NB: When working with electronic components/assemblies that are sensitive to EOS, never lay those items onto the outside surface of an anti-static bag or static shielding bag. The bag's interior surface/layer is engineered to have static-dissipative properties, but the bag's outer/exterior layer might not be static-dissipative. Furthermore, with static shielding bags, sharp wires on a circuit board can puncture the bag's outer plastic layer and make electrical contact with the bag's matallic-coated intermediate layer(s), thereby shorting together circuit board nodes that should not be shorted together.)*

Comment: My current setup is a ESD Mat and ESD Wristband both connected via alligator clips to unpainted screws that are screwed into a secondary PC Power supply (Not mounted in a PC Case). This Power Supply is then connected to an outlet. Would this be a good solution to be safe from static discharge and component safety from it? I use regular screw drivers and some of them are from a gunsmithing set some from an electronics set. Would these screw drivers cause damage since they are not specified ESD safe? Wouldn’t me touching the screw drivers ground them to the same level as me?

Comment: Regarding the ESD mat ground path.  Unplug the power supply from the wall and measure the resistance between the power plug's third-wire ground pin and the ground bond point on the ESD mat; the measured resistance should be less than one ohm.  _(NB: First measure the resistance of your multimeter's test leads by attaching the test leads to the multimeter, selecting ohms measurement mode, shorting the test lead tips together, and recording the measured resistance value. Subtract the measured test lead resistance from the measured ESD mat ground path resistance.)_

Comment: Regarding the hand tools.  Touching a metallic tool tip to ground immediately before touching the tool tip to an ESD-sensitive device/assembly is advisable. Be advised that static electricity can be generated by flowing fluids--e.g., air passing across a tool's metal tip as you handle the tool can generate static charge on the tip. That being said, my guess--and this is only a guess--is that static charge buildup that results from briefly moving a hand tool through still air (w/ perhaps 30% - 70% relative humidity) after touching the tool's tip to ground is probably insufficient to cause EOS.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a mounting screw of a PSU that is plugged in and switched off is an effective ground.

> Would this still cause static electricity to transfer since electrons transfer to what electronic you are working on since the power supply is not connected it it (like for instance a pc)?

Possibly, but you're probably going to touch the case of the other PC before you touch its internals, which should resolve any outstanding potential difference.

Comment: why possibility, I’m just curious as to how if the power supply should ground you? Do you think it is the most effective way of grounding yourself or is there a better way? Are you taking into account that the power supply is not attached to the case or pc in any way?

Comment: If the power supply has a three pronged connector (one prong being ground) connecting yourself to the case of it will almost certainly connect you to ground as long as it's plugged in.  Doesn't matter if it's on or not, the switch is rarely on ground.

Comment: @Luke - it will ground you because it's connected to ground :)  

- it's very effective at grounding you, but what you really want is to also ground the device you're working on. The easiest way to do this for a PC is to plug in the power cable (leave the switch off at the wall).  

- yes, I have noted that by touching the case of the PC to be worked on, you will ground it. It will not float to a significantly different potential in normal circumstances.

Comment: @abb So the best is to have the device grounded and to have yourself grounded with the second power supply? If the component is unable to be grounded via the power outlet, is having myself connected to the power supply effective or is there a better way? Thanks :)